# Filtering a huge Arraylist with more speed

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a huge Arraylist, I use a search input to filter this list. Once I enter the search term, the code iterates the list one by one, finding the matching items, adding them to a new list, displaying results from the new filtered list. I think this is the standard approach. But I'm looking for a more efficient method, like if I search for "A" the filtered list should contain all items beginning with "A", when I continue the input word and type "Ab", the code should iterate over the latest list which began with "A" only not the whole original list. And this should work in-reverse as well (like when I delete some letters). Is this even possible ?

Comment: One code snippets is worth a thousand words

Comment: you can save each previous search result in another list, and filter the previous result list instead of original

Comment: Also you may want to filter it multithreaded in case if device has more than one CPU core

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [trie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: XY problem, how do I filter a huge array list with more speed. Why an arraylist? nothing wrong with multiple data structures with similar data to help you optimize what you are trying to do. And what your looking for sounds like the classical example for what tries are for.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add Google [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) dependancy

```
api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'
```

and filter your Object list

```
    Iterable<Object> filtered = Iterables.filter(ObjectList, new Predicate<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Object o) {
        return yoursearchText.contains(o.getName());
        }
    });
```

I use this method for my Huge list of data.

Comment: Is using this one thing a good enough reason to introduce such a big dependency to a project?

Comment: how would it be faster than ordinary `ArrayList` iteration?

Comment: @pskink i don't know their mechanisam ,i am sure it is more faster then `Arraylist` iteration , but it is open source you should be check their

Comment: you are sure it is more faster? did you ever try it? if it iterates over all items in the `ObjectList` how come it would be faster if `apply()` method has to be called too?

Comment: yes i tried.. that but i am failed to achive my expected scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182710/discussion-between-nikunj-paradva-and-pskink).